# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I am getting the text 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0' returned from a spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() call. I'm not sure why. The spinner is tied to a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Here is the code

```
    cCategories = (Cursor) myAdapter.getAllCategories();
    this.startManagingCursor(cCategories);

    SimpleCursorAdapter scaCategories = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.track_category_item,cCategories,new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_CATEGORIES_NAME},new int[]{R.id.text1});
    scaCategories.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.track_category_dropdown_item); 
    mCatSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thecategory);
    mCatSpinner.setAdapter(scaCategories);

    if(mCatSpinner.isSelected() != true) {
        mCatSpinner.setSelection(0);
    }
```

and the xml
track_category_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true">
</TextView>
```

track_category_dropdown_item.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

The spinner xml looks like this

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/thecategory"
    android:prompt="@string/SELECT_CATEGORY"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="15px"
    android:layout_y="133px" >
</Spinner>
```

and the cursor being returned is

```
public Cursor getAllCategories() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_CATEGORIES_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_CATEGORIES_ROWID,
            KEY_CATEGORIES_NAME,
            KEY_CATEGORIES_DEFAULT}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}
```

The spinner appears to work properly. When I try to save this is what is passed as the value of the selected item using spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().

Anyone see anything blatently wrong here. not sure what to do.

thanks
patrick

Comment: This was working correctly with an ArrayAdapter. The value passed then was the text of the category (either Business, or Personal).Does the fact that I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter change how the value is passed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is working as you wrote it. `Spinner` is an `AdapterView`. The adapter you connected it to is a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. This means that the selected item is a `Cursor` (positioned at the item in the Cursor's result set corresponding with the user's choice). `Cursor` has the default implementation of `toString()`, which returns something like `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0`.

Since you didn't tell us what you are trying to do, it is impossible to accurately advise you further. Whatever it is you want to save, however, needs to be pulled out of the `Cursor` you get from `getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: Thanks commonsware, I think you may have answered my question. I am simply trying to take the value of the selected item, and save it to a database table. Initially I was using an ArrayAdapter to populate the spinner. The array was a single element array with a couple of categories ("Business", "Personal"). This worked as a string was passed.

So your saying I will need to do some additional coding to locate the actual categoryname from the cursor based on the passed spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()?

thanks

patrick

Comment: Yes. Given your `query()`, you would need to call `getString(1)` on the `Cursor`, to get back the 2nd column...assuming `KEY_CATEGORIES_NAME` is the value you seek.

Answer (score 2):

i can be bothered reading your context, but just wanted to briefly help.
i have a column named after `DbHelper.KEY_COL`, and i am retrieving a `DbHelper.KEY_COL` value at a specific row.
perhaps some of my code would help:

```
Cursor colCur=(Cursor)spCols.getSelectedItem();
String col=colCur.getString(colCur.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COL));
```